FastAPI background tasks do not work on Azure function apps
I followed the documentation to add background tasks to an Azure Function App with FastAPI:
async def background_task():
    logging.info("Background task started")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    logging.info("Background task finished")


@app.get("/do_background_task")
async def do_background_task(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(background_task)
    return {"message": "Background task started, this response should return immediately."}

However it does not work as expected and the response is only returned after 5 seconds.
To reproduce this I forked the Microsoft FastAPI example repo and added the code above. The forked repository with reproduction case can be found here.
It both fails when running locally and on Azure. Is this a limitation from Azure Functions or do I do something wrong?


However it does not work as expected and the response is only returned after 5 seconds.

Yes, it is expected behavior if you are using below code. BackgroundTasks  returns the response once all the background tasks are completed. In this case, it will return the message after 5sec of sleep time.
async def background_task():
    logging.info("Background task started")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    logging.info("Background task finished")


@app.get("/do_background_task")
async def do_background_task(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(background_task)
    return {"message": "Background task started, this response should return immediately."}

Output-
Background task finished message comes after 5sec of sleep time. That's why you are experiencing 5sec of delay in getting return message "Background task started, this response should return immediately.".

I am using below code to get immediate response.
def send_notification(message):
    logging.info(f'Notification will be sent over. Message: {message}')


def add_some_tasks(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, message: str):
    background_tasks.add_task(send_notification, message=message)
 
 
@app.get("/{msg}")
def send_msg(msg: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    add_some_tasks(background_tasks, message=msg)
    return {"message": "Request has been successfully submitted."}

Output-
I am getting expected response without any delay.


Portal-


The whole goal of background tasks is being able to give an immediate response to a user while still doing something in the background. The asyncio.sleep(5) is just a way to mimic a background task that actually takes some time.
Your code runs immediately because it's not doing any actual work. This also stated in the documentation:
"As connecting to an email server and sending an email tends to be "slow" (several seconds), you can return the response right away and send the email notification in the background."

@warreee refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71516140/fastapi-runs-api-calls-in-serial-instead-of-parallel-fashion/71517830#71517830 which says await asyncio.sleep() method will suspend the execution of the surrounding coroutine (until the sleep operation is completed) and in our case background_tasks.add_task(background_task) is a coroutine task

Afrim are you stating then that it is not possible to have an immediate response when you have something that takes a while e.g. sending an email? What is the purpose then of Background Tasks?

have you tried the example given in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/ for sending an email? In the BackgroundTasks documentation also, there is no use of asyncio.sleep() given.

@Afrim yes, I also added in the reproduction repository: https://github.com/warreee/fastapi-on-azure-functions-background-tasks/blob/main/WrapperFunction/init.py. When you run this you will see that you don't get an immediate response when it is writing to the file.

@warreee refer this https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#coroutines for coroutine function which says it might be paused internally too, whenever there is an await inside of it and in our function background_tasks.add_task(background_task) is a coroutine function.

@Afrim, are you saying that async functions that await for something are not possible to use as background tasks?
Regardless of that, why is the synchronous example not working then?
